# Partial declarations must not specify different base classes?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, inheritance

I see a number of other people asking about this error message in other questions, but I don't seem to understand enough about what's going on to fix this for myself. I created this error by having a WPF UserControl

```
public partial class EnterNewRequest : UserControl
```

But then later on I wanted to add a method to UserControl, so I used inheritance to stick it in there (can't use an extension because I need to override this method). But now my usercontrol is upset, and I'm not sure what in the xaml I need to change. The UserControl change block is in the namespace RCO_Manager. This is my xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="RCO_Manager.EnterNewRequest"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
```

Comment: What's the error? I never heard of a `WindowIsUpsetException`. Seems dreadful though!

Comment: @Baboon Check it out on msdn, it's based on the WindowsCantReadMyMindAndMagicallyFixThis class.

Comment: And what's the `InnerException` ?

Comment: @Baboon oh you wanted to know the error. I though you say it in the question title and were just making a joke. It's " Partial declarations must not specify different base classes," a compiler error

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same issue when I was working with Windows Phone. I can't remember the exact exception, but you can see the [XAML here on GitHub](https://github.com/cbenard/SimpleOAuth.Net/blob/master/SimpleOAuthTester.WP.Mango/MainPage.xaml), [the page code here](https://github.com/cbenard/SimpleOAuth.Net/blob/master/SimpleOAuthTester.WP.Mango/MainPage.xaml.cs), and the [base page code here](https://github.com/cbenard/SimpleOAuth.Net/blob/master/SimpleOAuthTester.WP.Mango/Classes/BasePhoneApplicationPage.cs) (mine was a base page, not base control). I needed to add a new `XAML` namespace and change the `<UserControl/>` declaration:

**Code Assumption**

```
namespace RCO_Manager
{
    // Inherits **Base**UserControl, not UserControl
    public partial class EnterNewRequest : BaseUserControl
    {
        // Magic goes here
        ...
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<local:BaseUserControl
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RCO_Manager"
    x:Class="RCO_Manager.EnterNewRequest"
```

**Side Note**

According to [Baboon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/677014/baboon), you don't need to specify it in your code-behind once you specify the base class in the `XAML`, so you can then change the code-behind to show the following. I can't verify it right now, but you can give this a try after you get it working.

```
public partial class EnterNewRequest // Don't specify BaseUserControl here
{
    ...
```

Comment: By the way, declaring base class in both XAML and code-behind is redundant.

Comment: At least with Windows Phone, I got the same `WindowIsUpsetException` when I didn't only put the BaseUserControl in the code and not the XAML. Maybe it'll fix his issue too? I'll update my answer to say I had the same problem.

Comment: But yes, making a class that inherits UserControl then making your control inherit from it should be the way to go.

Comment: This still isn't working, I've tried this with both regular UserControl and with a newly inherited one. My xaml is <local:UserControl x:Class="RCO_Manager.EnterNewRequest"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace.RCO_Manager"    But all it say is "The type local:usercontrol was not found." What am I missing here?

Comment: You typed it wrong. It's `clr-namespace:RCO_Manager`, not `clr-namespace.RCO_Manager`. Colon, not period. Also, it's not `<local:UserControl/>`, it's `<local:BaseUserControl/>`. Please read my answer again.

Comment: When I typed clr-namespace:RCO_Manager, Visual Studio balked at me about it being improperly formatted (so I assumed it was a typo, which it thought clr-namespace.RCO_manager was fine) though now it likes the : so I don't know what has changed. Regardless, I use local:UserControl because that's what my class is named, not BaseUserControl. Apparently xaml doesn't like me using the class names in that way though

Comment: @cost, Your class isn't called UserControl. It's called `EnterNewRequest`. What does it inherit from? You said you were inheriting from something that is not `UserControl`.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't word it in my question very well. EnterNewRequest inherits from UserControl, but then later on I tried to modify UserControl to add a method to it (instead of creating a new class and having it inherit UserControl and then having EnterNewRequest inherit that). But when I added the method to UserControl, EnterNewRequest failed to work

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9682/discussion-between-chris-benard-and-cost)

Comment: Hey, thanks for all of your help with this, but this created a new issue which I didn't notice last night. Now the design view window doesn't work. I get an InstanceBuilderException. "Cannot create an instance of BaseUserControl." The project still compiles and works fine, but now I can't see anything on the design view screen. Googling this looks like it's a bug characteristic of older VS versions, not 2010. Any thoughts on a solution?

Comment: This goes back to it being an abstract class, doesn't it. I think I may know how to fix this..

Comment: And one more comment to my friend Chris Bernard, who was nice enough to explain the usefulness of abstract to me in chat. It turns out I can't use abstract with a usercontrol like this, because the design view needs to be able to instantiate the object to show it. I didn't want to use an interface because I needed to store some variables as well.

Comment: You need to add a default constructor to your base class. Then it'll work fine in the designer.